# Set HTTP Expires Header in DotNetNuke?

Tags: caching, http-headers, dotnetnuke

How can I set the the HTTP Expires header in DotNetNuke generated pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I have confirmed that this works on IIS 7 and DNN 5.6**

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on the DNN website
3. Double Click HTTP Response Headers
4. Click (upper right) Set Common Headers
5. Check the Checkbox "Expire Web Content"
6. Enter your desired TTL
7. Press OK
8. Verify with Firebug

**To verify that it is working:**

1. Open Firebug Net Tab
2. Reload page
3. Browse to any of the page resources
4. Click the "+"
5. Look for "Cache-Control  no-cache"

**Caching of Dynamic Content**

DNN has internal caching for dynamic content. To adjust this, go into the host settings and turn off caching. That has nothing to do with HTTP Headers. Note: It's best to adjust caching at the module-level rather than host level. DNN is built to run with heavy caching. It can be lightning-fast if configured correctly, and very slow without caching.

Comment: I've tried the above but it only works on static resources within the page, e.g. jpegs, css files. However, the page itself, which was generated dynamically by DNN, is not cached at all.

Comment: DNN has internal caching for dynamic content. Go into your host settings and turn off caching. That has nothing to do with HTTP Headers